# Best practices for data storage and UITableView vs UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a best practices question about how (or even if) I should store data. Disclaimer: I'm a noob. Okay so right now I have an application that's using a UIWebView to browse a wordpress based site. However, I'm thinking about switching it to a UITableView and loading the data from the RSS feed so that I have tighter control over the way the site looks in the application.

**The problem:**
Wordpress site's usually only hand out the last 10 (sometimes 20) posts. So if I don't store data, the user would only see the last 10 (or 20) posts from that particular site every time they restart the app.

**The solution (?):**
Store the data, but how? Write to a Plist file or use core data (something I haven't done yet). Third option I don't know about? If the solution is to store the data, how much of it do I store, the entire post? Just the headline, meta data and excerpt?

I'm not really sure what the iOS way of doing things is, so I guess I'm just sort of looking for someone to point me in the right direction for how I should solve the problem. Or should I just stick with my UIWebView?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a **huge** Core Data fan.

I would definitely go with Core Data here. Especially if you're going to use a UITableView to display the data because you get to use the lovely `NSFetchedResultsController`. Now I know that jumping in to Core Data can be daunting, but I recommend taking the time to get comfortable. It's to the point where I use Core Data for nearly all of my data persistence needs.

How much to store is up to you. Depends on the needs of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use `Core Data`. You could write it to a file or use `NSUserDefaults` but the recommended way to handle what you need to do would be to use `Core Data`.

You can store whatever fields you want, you just need to store whatever information you are going to want to access without having to re-pull data from the website.